# I am getting error in firebase database function get()

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am facing a problem for 2-3 days I am trying to fix it but I can't fix it.
I am continuously getting errors on a Firebase Realtime Database function **get()** on a code that I have copied from Firebase Realtime Database documentation. Here is my code:

```java
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

// ...
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user app/profile");
//...
mDatabase.child(uid).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < DataSnapshot > () {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < DataSnapshot > task) {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            _custom_smart_toast(String.valueOf(task.getException()), setting.getString("color", ""), 10, setting.getString("color", ""));
        } else {
            _custom_smart_toast(String.valueOf(task.getResult().getValue()), setting.getString("color", ""), 10, setting.getString("color", ""));
        }
    }
}
```

Build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tsd.html"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.3"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
}
```

I am getting error on compiling code that is:

> The method get() is undefined for the type DatabaseReference

Comment: Please edit your question and show the dependencies that you're using.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have add dependency please check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get()` method isn't recognized because you're using an old version of the Realtime Database dependency. The get() method is available [starting from version 19.6.0](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5).

To be able to use `get()`, you need to update the dependency to the [latest available version](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#java), which is:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.1.0'
```

But I strongly advise you to use the BOM version without specifying the version for each product that you're using:

```
implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.2")
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage"
```

If you're using Kotlin, here are the corresponding [dependencies](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#kotlin+ktx):

```
implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.2")
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx"
```